# Draw Activity below cutout in landscape

Tags: android, display-cutouts

Similar to [Activity not extended below the cutout in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64346864/4833070), but the answer there is limiting.

In landscape, the camera cutout is on the left. I used

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

to stretch the background color below it:

[image]

I would like to actually render some elements (like the title panel) below the cutout area. Is this possible, without entering full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need set `window_flags`, we can use `WindowCompat` from `androidx.appcompat`.

Add this in your activity `onCreate`. This asks the system to lay out your activity edge to edge.

```kotlin
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Then you need to add necessary padding to your content that should not be blocked. For example, here I have added padding to my `AppBar`.
This is achieved by setting an inset listener callback on any view once.

```kotlin
binding.topBar.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->

    val compatInset = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(insets)
            .getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
   binding.topBar.updatePadding(left = compatInset.left, top = compatInset.top, right = compatInset.right)

    return@setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener insets
}
```

You mostly only want to deal with `systemBars` as cutouts usually change the systemBar's size. Unless you are targeting a specific device cutout.